# Function arguments destructuring vs destructuring in body

Tags: javascript

can someone please give me a brief explanation what's the difference between destructuring incoming data in function arguments vs destructuring the arguments in function body. Or if you can to give me the link to source where I can learn more about this (google didn't helped me yet).

I wan't to understand what's the implication behind this or it's just syntactical sugar.

Version 1:

```
function test({ name, id }) {
    // do something with id and name
}
```

Version 2:

```
function test(data) {
    const { name, id } = data;
    // do something with id and name
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: version 1 ... `id` and `name` are overwritable - version 2 - they are not

Comment: @JaromandaX also, in version 2 you can (more easily) use the other properties from the argument, if any. E.g., `data.foo`.

Comment: @VLAZ - I was going to mention that too, but thought that was obvious :p

Comment: @JaromandaX just wanted to add it for completeness. :)

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand about overwriting. Should I assume the v1 in the end is equal to v2, only that in v2 you have more control. In the end the lexical scope will be the same v1 and v2 will create 2 variables in function body?

Comment: sounds about right

Comment: when i need to pass alot of parameters to an function lets say 6 parameters. I would rather use version 1 then 2. I just need to take care about the names instead of the sequence how i pass them